# jQuery children() not selecting tfoot tr element

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML.

```
<div>
    <table></table>
    <div><table id="startingPoint"></table></div>
    <table><tfoot><tr id="getThis"></tr></tfoot></table>
</div>
```

Using find() selects #getThis as expected.

```
$('#startingPoint').parent().next().find('tfoot tr')
```

Using children() doesn't select #getThis.  Why?

```
$('#startingPoint').parent().next().children('tfoot tr')
```

Comment: the tr element is not a child of the table, and can't be selected with `children`. you have to use `find` if you are not searching for direct children

Comment: @Darhazer.  Understood that tr isn't a direct child, but expected tfoot tr to be interpreted as one.

Comment: So, I take it would need to be something like : `$('#startingPoint').parent().next().children('tfoot').children('tr')`?

Comment: *The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree* - http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `children` works, it takes all of the direct children of the element and then matches them all against the selector.  None of the directly children match the selector `tfoot tr`.

In reality, there is no situation where this selector could ever match a direct child as it really contradicts itself.  It is asking for direct children which are descendents of a descendent.  (Essentially a direct child that is also at least a grandchild).

I believe this would do what you are trying to do:

```
$('#startingPoint').parent().next().find('> tfoot > tr')
```

Note that `>` is the child selector.  This will get any `tr` that is a direct child of  a `tfoot` which is a direct child of the table.

Comment: Thanks James.  Not only did you answer my question, you taught me about `>` selector which I wasn't aware of.